# Accessing dynamic form field variables from google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a standalone app that generates sequential form fields. I can't figure out how to access these fields with an incremental variable.

In my htmlscript page:

```
<form id="myForm">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" size="30"><br>
<? var listsize = data.length; 
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>  
  <input type="checkbox" name="field<?= i ?>" value="Y"><?!= data[i]?><br>
<? } ?>
<input type="hidden" name="totalitems" value="<?= listsize?>">
<input type='button' onclick='google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode)' value='submit' name="submit">
</form>
```

so that would generate a bunch of checkboxes named "field0", "field1", "field2" etc.

Now in my .gs file:

```
function processForm(theForm) {

  var htmlBody =  'Hi '+theForm.firstname',<br>';

  for (var i = 0; i < theForm.totalitems; ++i) {
       var fieldname = "field" + i;
       htmlBody+= theForm.parameter['field'+i];// this does not work
       htmlBody+= theForm.['field'+i];         // this does not work
       htmlBody+= theForm.('field'+i);         // this does not work

  }
}
```

I can access one of the dynamic form fields directly with theForm.field7 for example, but I have no idea how to access it in a for loop using a variable "fieldX"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
    htmlBody+= theForm['field'+i.toString()];
```

had to remove .parameter

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
htmlBody+= theForm.parameter['field'+i.toString()];
```

Comment: @Sam It would be better to post the code that works for you in separate answer, rather than edit this one. You can answer to your own question and mark that as accepted as well.

Comment: I have to wait 46 minutes to self-answer :-) newbie account